# Al borrar capas del View se bloquea la aplicación

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

Tengo una aplicación muy simple. Que dibuja líneas cuando tocas la pantalla con dos dedos, cuando levantan los dedos quiero borrar el dibujo, y cuando dibujen de nuevo muestre nuevas líneas.

Sin embargo, cuando borro las líneas la primera vez, la siguiente pulsación causa un error con ningún mensaje de error. Me imagino que estoy haciendo algo pequeño mal, pero no puedo entenderlo. Aquí está mi código:

```
var prevX: CGFloat!
var prevY: CGFloat!

var startX: CGFloat = 150
var startY : CGFloat = 450

var reset: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:")
    pan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    pan.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

func pan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print(self.view.layer)
    var state = recognizer.state

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        reset = true
        var sublayers = self.view.layer.sublayers
        for layer in sublayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    } else {
        var interval = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if (reset) {
            reset = false
            prevX = CGFloat(startX + interval.x)
            prevY = CGFloat(startY + interval.y)
        }
        var newPointX = startX + interval.x
        var newPointY = startY + interval.y

        var path = UIBezierPath().bezierPathByReversingPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: prevX, y: prevY))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:newPointX, y:newPointY))

        var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        prevX = newPointX
        prevY = newPointY

    }
}
```

Un poco mas información sobre el error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1, address=0x499e....
     ___UIApplicationExtensionGetAccurateShareServicesExtensionForIdentifier_block_invoke_2
    0x18c00e3c0:  adrp   x8, 54568
    0x18c00e3c4:  ldr    x8, [x8, #2248]
    0x18c00e3c8:  ldr    x8, [x8]
    0x18c00e3cc:  ldr    x9, [sp, #56]
    0x18c00e3d0:  sub    x8, x8, x9
    0x18c00e3d4:  cbnz   x8, 0x18c00e3fc           ; UIApplicationMain + 1548
    0x18c00e3d8:  movz   w0, #0
```

Yo creo que es esta linea lo que esta causando el error.

```
        for layer in sublayers {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
```

porque si la remuevo el programa funciona sin ningun problema ( *pero no borra la las lineas* )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estás modificando el tamaño del Array de layers directamente. Para arreglarlo, añade la siguiente variable:

```
var layers = [CALayer]()
```

Después, cada vez que "pintes" una línea, guárdala en dicha variable:

```
layers.append(shapeLayer)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Y por último:

```
if (state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {

      reset = true
      for l in layers {
          l.removeFromSuperlayer()
      }

}
```

Con esto ya no tendrás problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una subclase de `CAShapeLayer` y usar esa subclase. Entonces cuando vayas a borrar las líneas, puedes hacer una comprobación previa como esta:

```
// supongamos que la subclase de llama MyShapeLayer
for layer in sublayers {
    if layer is MyShapeLayer {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Esto te debería funcionar.